# Python 3.5.2 - How to detect a program running i.e "chrome.exe" using stock modules

Tags: python

If I wanted to have a program that detects program running such as 'chrome.exe' then opens a program `message.txt` in this case

Psuedocode:

```
import os
if "chrome.exe" is running:
   os.startfile("message.txt")
```

Comment: [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) module gives list of running processes and its names.

Answer (score 1):

You could you below too as [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) said. Thanks furas. :smile:

```html
import psutil as psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    proc_name = proc.name()
    if proc_name == 'chrome.exe':
        print('chrome is running now.')

        # open your program in this position

    else:
        print(proc_name)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Can you just run through how to install psutil?

Comment: Check [this link](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) to install psutil package for your system.

Answer (score 0):

You could use wmi package to check running process in windows like below snippet.

```html
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()

for process in c.Win32_Process():
    if process.Name == 'chrome.exe':
        print('chrome is running now.')

        # open your program in this position
        
    else:
        print(process.Name)
```

Comment: And you could use below too. 

```
import psutil as psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    proc_name = proc.name()
    if proc_name == 'chrome.exe':
        print('chrome is running now.')

        # open your program in this position

    else:
        print(proc_name)

```

@furas Thanks